# Is there an umbrella term for sanitary plastic equipment such as hair salon aprons, gloves, etc?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

So, I'm looking for a general term/phrase to refer to sanitary plastic equipment. Suppose there's a manufacturer which produces plastic products such as hair salon aprons, gloves, masks, and so on, what would one say they produce?

> sanitary plastic ware?
>   sanitary plastic equipment?
>   hygienic plastic equipment?
>   hygiene work wear?

Honestly I would share the result of my research with you guys here, but I've been looking up definitions for an hour now and I haven't been able to reach a conclusive result. Hence, My question here.

Answer (score 1):

The term I've heard a lot recently is "personal protective equipment" (PPE) for masks, gloves, and other wearable items. Other terms might be "safety products" or "protective products."

"Plastic products" is a generic terms for things made of plastic. Plastic knives, forks, plates, etc. are called plastic tableware.

"Sanitary" products has a very different meaning, referring to toilet paper, personal wipes, feminine hygiene products, etc. "Cleaning products" refers to sponges, cleansers and so on.